Recursive CTE across 2 tables to find the top of the hierarchy
Create a documents table:
CREATE TABLE documents
(
    objectid char(16), 
    objectname char(80)
)

INSERT INTO documents (objectid, objectname) 
VALUES ('456', 'Test document'), 
       ('123', 'Folder'), 
       ('121', 'Upper folder'), 
       ('120', 'Parent')

Create a relationships table:
CREATE table relationships (objectid char(16), parent char(16))

INSERT INTO relationships (objectid, parent) 
VALUES ('121', '120'), ('123', '121'), ('456', '123')

I am trying to use a SQL query to return the top relationship of each document like so:



objectid
topcontainer




120
120


121
120


123
120


456
120



I tried to use the following query, but it is not working. Not sure why but it terminates.
WITH c AS 
(
    SELECT d.objectid, r.parent, r.parent AS topcontainer
    FROM documents d
    JOIN relationships r ON d.objectid = r.objectid

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
        t.objectid, t.parent, c.topcontainer 
    FROM   
        relationships AS t
    JOIN 
        c ON t.parent = c.parent 
) 
SELECT objectid, topcontainer 
FROM c 
ORDER BY c.objectid


Can't you just join them? Like SELECT * FROM documents JOIN relationships ON d.id = r.parentId?

You can actually do this with a single CTE, by using left-joins. Unfortunately, SQL Server does not allow an actual LEFT JOIN in the recursive part of a recursive CTE, but you can simulate it with OUTER APPLY.
What this does is it keeps joining the recursion until the end, then left-joins it one more time, so that we get a single row with cte.parent IS NULL per objectid.
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT d.objectid, r.parent, r.parent AS topParent
    FROM documents d
    LEFT JOIN relationships r ON r.objectid = d.objectid

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT cte.objectid, r.parent, ISNULL(r.parent, cte.topParent)
    FROM cte
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT r.*
        FROM relationships AS r
        WHERE r.objectid = cte.parent
    ) r
    WHERE cte.parent IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT
    cte.objectid,
    ISNULL(cte.topParent, cte.objectid) AS topParent
FROM cte
WHERE cte.parent IS NULL;

db<>fiddle

Nice, I changed tack when I realised a left join wasn't an option. I'll remember this.

The following returns the results you wish to achieve. I refactored it a bit to make it clearer (only joining in the recursive section makes more sense to me), but the key issue was in fact that this JOIN c ON t.parent = c.parent should have been this JOIN c ON t.objectid = c.parent i.e. the ParentId of the query should join to the ObjectId of the joined relationship, giving a new ParentId and so on.
And then to get the results you desire, we need to filter out all but the topmost recursion result per document. This requires a second CTE to compute the max level because we can't use the result in the WHERE clause in the same query its calculated.
WITH c1 AS 
(
    SELECT d.ObjectId, d.ObjectId ParentId, 0 Level
    FROM documents d

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT c1.ObjectId, t.Parent ParentId, Level + 1
    FROM c1    
    JOIN relationships AS t
        ON t.ObjectId = c1.ParentId 
), c2 AS (
  SELECT ObjectId, ParentId, Level
    , MAX(Level) OVER (PARTITION BY objectid) MaxLevel
  FROM c1 
)
SELECT ObjectId, ParentId
FROM c2
WHERE Level = MaxLevel
ORDER BY ObjectID;




ObjectId
ParentId




120
120


121
120


123
120


456
120



Fiddle
